# Use routing in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm a newbie in the MVC world. My issue is that I want to use the same controller for several URL request.

Issue:
I have a company containing three departments.

I want to access the HomeController/Index from all of these requests.

1. www.company.com/Home/Index -> typing: www.company.com/
2. ww.company.com/department1/Home/Index -> typing:www.company.com/Department1
3. ww.company.com/department2/Home/Index -> typing:www.company.com/Department2

This Maproute will work but if I request a controller different then default I have to type something like this (main company). www.company.com/something/NewController/SomeAction. If I want to request this for the main company I want to type www.company.com/NewController/SomeAction. How do I solve this in MVC3?

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    "area", // Route name
    "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { area = "area", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you want to access **Index** view from all of your controllor actions.

then You could place Index in shared folder such a way - MVC will display Index Page 
as

*
www.company.com/Shared/Index
*

```
*I want to access the HomeController/Index from all of these requests.
    www.company.com/Home/Index -> typing: www.company.com/
    ww.company.com/department1/Home/Index -> typing:www.company.com/Department1
    ww.company.com/department2/Home/Index -> typing:www.company.com/Department2*
```

Comment: The url for the main site wil be www.company.com/HomeController/Index, and for each department www.company.com/department1/HomeController/Index. The first URL will now faild (according to mye MapRoute) because HomeController will be in the "area" part and "Index" is not a valid Controller. The question ends up lik this. How can I route to the same controller with or without "area" filled in (area is optional)?